# HTML/CSS <ul> tag within <li> tag - Elements sitting around move

Tags: html, css

"ul" tag within a "li" tag :

```
<li data-role="dropdown">
    <a href="#">
       Au sujet de
    </a>
    <ul>
        <li>Mon CV</li>
        <li>
             <a href="/personality">
                 Ma personnalit&eacute;
             </a>
        </li>
        <li>Mes Hobbies</li>
        <li>Mes formations</li>
        <li>Mon mémoire</li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And the CSS properties for this code :

```
#mainMenu > li > ul {
    display:none;
}

#mainMenu > li:hover > ul {
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-top:15px;
    z-index: 1500;
    background-color:#F2F2F7;
}
```

When I'm hover the main 'li' tag, all the text around move.

Does it exist a css property to prevent the mouvement of the different elements around the menu when I'm hover it ? Otherwise, does it exist another solution ?

Thank you

Comment: what is `#mainMenu`. probably a parent `ul`. But even I didn't reproduced the issue http://jsfiddle.net/d2sA4/

Comment: I'm convinced he means "move the elements before or after the `ul`". So the solutions might be to use `position: absolute`. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want one element to affect the position of other elements around it, use the `position: absolute` property.

For example:

```
#mainMenu > li:hover > ul {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: `absolute` or `relative`? please update your answer.

Comment: Thanks, my mind obviously wasn't functioning when I wrote the code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to position absolute the inner ul.

```
    #mainMenu > li:hover > ul {
      display:block;
      text-decoration:none;
      list-style-type:none;
      padding: 15px 10px;
      z-index: 1500;
      background-color:#F2F2F7;
      position: absolute;
    }
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JyLjH/